# How can I make a django datetime field dependent on another field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model and modelform defined as follows

```
class Article(models.Model):
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.is_draft == False) and (self.date_published == None):
            self.date_published = datetime.now()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ArticleForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['is_draft']

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        article = Article(**self.cleaned_data)
        article.save()
```

What is strange is that when I add the custom save method to the model, the parameters for the save method from ArticleForm get passed to it. That is, force_insert=False, force_update=False are passed into the Article save method as well. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'd look at the self.cleaned_data and see if it has force_**

Comment: Ran your code, could not reproduce the problem: ``Article.save()`` do not get the ``force_insert`` and ``force_update`` parameters. Could you provide a list of parameters passed both to form and model save methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArticleForm.save()` parameters are not used in `Article.save()` method unless you pass them explicitly. `force_insert` and `force_update` are default `Model.save()` arguments, as stated in [Django model save documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects). Their values depend on how you call the `Model.save()` method.

Also, your **Article** save method should look like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.is_draft == False) and (self.date_published == None):
            self.date_published = datetime.now()
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```